# Tulip Lens Hood in Autofocus mode

Tags: dslr, autofocus, digital, lens-hood

I use a Canon Rebel T3i, which has a rotating front element. I would prefer using a tulip shaped hood, especially for wide angle shots. However, the orientation angle of the hood changes during autofocus and can show up in the field of view as well.

I am currently setting the focus to manual and roughly get it right. Then the AF does the remaining but slight adjustment, and would prefer an easier alternative. What do you say?

Comment: Even if the front element rotates, I have never seen a hood attach to the rotating part, it would be silly to design such thing!

Comment: @Itai isn't that what some of the kit lenses are like? Certainly the filter threads are on the rotating part of the front element, meaning you have to persistently check the a polarising filter. I definitely had this issue on my old entry level Canon 8-55 kit lens, and fitting a lens hood to that would have caused the same issue. Silly or not, it was the design

Comment: Usually the filter thread rotates on those but the hood is fixed to the barrel which does not. Again, I said *usually* because I did not check every possible lens.

Comment: Can you confirm the lens and whether it's a proper lens hood OR a petal shaped one that attached via the filter thread?

Comment: @CrazyDino, I face this issue with the kit lens and it is indeed a petal shaped one attached via the filter thread.

Comment: @gpavanb which kit lens? If it's one that's supposed to have a cylindrical good would allow me to write a correct answer.

Comment: @Itai There are quite a few third party sellers that are selling screw on tulip shaped hoods to gullible, unsuspecting owners of lenses that rotate the front element when focusing and/or zooming. These hoods either a) cause vignetting when improperly positioned or b) provide less protection because their maximum lengths are no longer than a normal cone shaped hood for such a lens would be and the cutouts to make the hood tulip shaped are unnecessary to prevent vignetting and only allow more off axis light to strike the front of the lens than a proper conical hood.

Answer (score 2):

On the assumption that you're using one of the non-STM 18-55 lenses, the obvious solution here is to upgrade either to the 18-55 STM lens, or a more dedicated wide angle lens, none of which will have a rotating front element and your problem just goes away.